Prevent line break before french quotation marks
Simple question today. I'm using this preamble for languages:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

and I use french quotation marks just by inserting them in my text with Alt+0171 and Alt+0187 which give me « and ».
My problem is that doing it that way, I happen to have line breaks between quotation marks and the text within :

with the following code:
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=Turquoise!5!white,colframe=Turquoise!95!black,drop shadow=greenforcoolerblue,breakable,title=\textbf{Heuristique}]
Deux problèmes apparaissent : la terminaison, liée à des propriétés de noethérianité : « on ne peut pas réécrire indéfiniment » ; la confluence, par exemple : $ststs$ peut se récrire $tstts$ et $sttst$ selon qu'on considère les trois premières ou trois dernières lettres. \\
La conjonction de la terminaison et de la confluence donne de la convergence. Si le système de réécriture est convergent, alors on pourra résoudre le problème du mot par l'\ital{algorithme de la forme normale}.
\end{tcolorbox}

I want to know if there is a way to fix this whitout defining a new command.

Can you please add an example paragraph where the issue appears?

I've just added a photograph.

Please, add the text as code, so we don't have to retype it.

OK. I just did.

Please add a full minimal working example (MWE) that we can compile.

Sorry, but it's important to know also the line width you have, because with the standard one the line breaks are completely different.

Does it also happen when you remove the spaces between the quotation marks and the text, i.e., «on ne peut pas réécrire indéfiniment» instead of « on ne peut pas réécrire indéfiniment »?

You can also get french quotes with \frquote{something} or \og{} something \fg{} from the package babel-french.

See this answer

Marijn : No, but there isn't any space anymore between the text and the quotation marks, and I don't want that.

I can reproduce the same layout with hmargin=2cm passed to geometry.

What you need is the correct translation for French, which isn't just “print guillemets”, because spaces have to be taken into account.
Meanwhile, I suggest a few changes:

since your language appears to be French, you don't need english; the main language has to go last anyway;

use \newtcolorbox, so you don't need to type again and again the same specifications; choose a different name, if you prefer;

I changed \ital into \emph, because the former command is unknown;

\\ should not be used to end paragraphs.


The idea is to make LaTeX translate « and » into \og and \fg.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\newtcolorbox{scholium}[1]{
  colback=Turquoise!5!white,
  colframe=Turquoise!95!black,
  drop shadow=greenforcoolerblue,
  breakable,
  title=\textbf{#1},
}

%%% solution to the issue
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00AB}{\og\ignorespaces}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00BB}{\fg}

\begin{document}

\begin{scholium}{Heuristique}
Deux problèmes apparaissent : la terminaison, liée à des propriétés 
de noethérianité : « on ne peut pas réécrire indéfiniment » ; 
la confluence, par exemple : $ststs$ peut se récrire $tstts$ et 
$sttst$ selon qu'on considère les trois premières ou trois dernières lettres.

La conjonction de la terminaison et de la confluence donne de la convergence. 
Si le système de réécriture est convergent, alors on pourra résoudre 
le problème du mot par l'\emph{algorithme de la forme normale}.
\end{scholium}


\end{document}



Thank you so much! You didn't even give me time to put a MWE. Thank you also for your tips, although I already use newtcolorbox.

@LouisLascaud Next time, please, do.
